# Update a DOM later when it has an images. This is running under a ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading, ionic4

*home.ts*

```
myMethod(){
   this.eventService.getUserEvents(uid).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.setEvents(res);
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('request completed')
          );
}

setEvents(events: EventModel[]) {
     forEach(events, async (event: EventModel) => {

     // Call Server API here
     const photoResponseModel: PhotoResponseModel = await this.photoService.getPhoto(event.displayPhotoPath); 

      const eventModel: EventModel = {
          attendanceStatus: event.attendanceStatus,
          imageUrl: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(photoResponseModel.dataUrl)
        };

        switch (eventModel.attendanceStatus) {
          case AttendanceStatusEnum.ATTENDED: {
            this.attendedEvents.push(eventModel);
            break;
          }
          case AttendanceStatusEnum.INVITED: {
            this.invitedEvents.push(eventModel);
            break;
          }
          default:
        }
       });
    });
  }
```

*home.html*

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let attendedEvent of attendedEvents">
  <ion-card-content>
    <img [src]="attendedEvent.imageUrl"> <---- Image URL here
    <ion-item>
      {{attendedEvent.title}}
    </ion-item>
   </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Here you can see that the above coding pattern is very bad due to performance issues. i.e. If it has 10 events then it goes to the server 10 times to bring the image. Can you tell me a more optimized architecture here?

Is there any way to bind images later after showing the other things first. I know about this [ng-lazyload-image](https://github.com/tjoskar/ng-lazyload-image) library. Any clue about how can I use it here? My biggest problem here is there are lot of events and it can have 1 image per event. Since HTML has a loop how can I update it if I'll retrieve the images later?

Here I can use `Promise.all` to bring all the images once. But how can I update dom for these images only?

Any idea about how to architect this use case in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 100 events - which means you have to load 100 images. You don't want the client to load all of them at once.

Fortunately, you have a few options:

1. use the [native `loading="lazy"`](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/) which has been introduced in Chrome 75.
2. use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). This API allows us to determine if an existing element is visible in the viewport and if so, we could add the `img` (which will trigger loading the image).

This way, the client will download several images in the first load (instead of all of them, opposed to your original code), and when he scrolls down, other images will be downloaded as well.

---

BTW, you may want to `.subscribe` only in the view (via [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)) and not in the component itself. Something like this:

```
userEvents$ = this.eventService.getUserEvents(uid)
  .pipe(
    tap(response => this.setEvents(response)),
    catchError(error => console.error(error)),
    tap(() => console.log('done'));
```

and in the view, you simply do:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userEvents$ | async as userEvents">
  <!-- Angular will unsubscribe when this component is destryoed -->
</ng-container>
```

This way, you prevent a memory leak since Angular will unsubscribe automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this. Can you explain how this will solve my issue?

Comment: @Sampath I have updated my answer. I can't write all of the code since it takes some time to do so.